# Trying to find a short story with a cowboy and psychologist who knows he's delusional

Tags: story-identification

I can't remember where I read this short story, but the plot is that a cowboy perches on the edge of a cliff looking for Black Bart or some such other villain to ride up.

From behind the cowboy comes a psychologist who explains kindly to the cowboy that he's experiencing a delusion which has thrown him back into the old West, and that none of this is real - no gun, no cliff, no Black Bart.  To prove it, the psychologist walks out in front of him, and promptly falls off the cliff to his death.  The cowboy shakes his head and picks up his rifle because he sees Black Bart riding up in the distance.

Any clues?  No idea as to title or author but it might have been in an anthology of Hugo or Nebula winners.

Comment: What about it is scifi/fantasy?

Comment: Probably the psychiatrist falling off the imaginary cliff...

Comment: An alternate scifi/fantasy element is that it is set in a universe where psychology is a hard science. *::turns snark mode off::*

Answer (score 18):

It's called "[Texas Week](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/28647)" by [Albert Hernhuter](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?18935). You may have read it in [*50 Short Science Fiction Tales*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?403556) edited by Isaac Asimov.

Comment: It's available via Project Gutenberg, although the links are not working for me today.

Comment: Wow that was crazy fast.  Thanks for your help Sean.

Comment: :) I just edited the link in.

Comment: Oh wait... he's Sean too. Now that's confusing.

Comment: It's also in one of the sci-fi shorts collection (numbered less than 20, but I don't recall exactly which one) on librivox.

Comment: @dmckee Vol. 016 [it says here](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?291234). ***Why*** do you people hate the ISFDB?